# Restful service in MS Dynamics

Tags: java, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a requirement to create restful service using WebApi in MS Dynamics and create a client in Java and hit the MS Dynamics Web Service. If I want to create a restful service in MS Dynamics through WebApi, is it mandatory that I need to have OAUTH implemented? Can create a service and hit from Java without authentication?

My another question is, is it possible to use our custom authentication method like call a another web service from MS Dynamics and validate and if authorised user then send data.

I am ok in implementing Java client but I am not familiar with MS Dynamics and not able to find any help from net.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from Jason Lattimer's blog post: [CRM Web API Using Java](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2015/11/24/crm-web-api-using-java)

> Again our friends at Microsoft help us out on the authentication front
>   by providing a version of the Azure Active Directory Authentication
>   Library (ADAL) for Java. You can set up a Maven dependency with the
>   info here:
>   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j
>
> In this case I’m authentication using a hardcoded username and
>   password.

```
//Azure Application Client ID
private final static String CLIENT_ID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
//CRM URL
private final static String RESOURCE = "https://org.crm.dynamics.com";
//O365 credentials for authentication w/o login prompt
private final static String USERNAME = "administrator@org.onmicrosoft.com";
private final static String PASSWORD = "password";
//Azure Directory OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT
private final static String AUTHORITY = 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

AuthenticationContext context = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;
ExecutorService service = null;
try {
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(RESOURCE,
            CLIENT_ID,
            USERNAME,
            PASSWORD, null);
    result = future.get();
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}

String token = result.getAccessToken();
```

> The other thing I stumbled upon is that Java’s HttpURLConnection for
>   making HTTP requests doesn’t support the PATCH method natively (which
>   is used by the Web API when doing updates to multiple fields). This
>   was solved specifying a POST method and adding an additional
>   “X-HTTP-Method-Override” property.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

> You can check out the code on GitHub:
>   https://github.com/jlattimer/CrmWebApiJava

Comment: This answer is overly vulnerable to link decay. Can you summarize this in a way that answers the question?

Comment: I have added the example from Jason Lattimer's blog

Comment: Great! Thanks for improving it.

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
This only works if the receiving end supports it. But unfortunately Microsoft Dynamics does not support the method override.